# How can I tell if my accommodation is earthquake-proof?

Tags: hotels, romania, natural-disasters

I'm travelling to Bucharest (Romania), which is [at risk of earthquakes](https://www.euronews.com/my-europe/2021/04/16/residents-of-bucharest-s-crumbling-buildings-live-in-fear-of-earthquake-threat).  How can I tell if my hotel or other accommodation is propertly built and safe from earthquakes?

Comment: why risk? go camping and pick a spot away from hills, poles, trees ;) !

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a program that will mark at-risk buildings in Bucharest; kinda scary, but good for them to acknowledge this.

old 2012 article :
https://www.thestar.com/news/world/2012/12/08/bucharest_marks_buildings_likely_to_collapse_in_earthquake.html

I assume there is a website somewhere with a comprehensive list.

Also, ask the hotels you want to book at.

Most recent construction should be more earthquake proof (local and probably european construction code)

https://www.one.ro/en/blog/how-building-regulations-changed-after-the-77-earthquake/

Comment: I also assume there is such a website, but I haven't found it yet.  Might be only in Romanian.  I don't know if a hotel would give an honest answer.